# How to extract XML node values and from recurring nodes in pentaho?

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes, pentaho, kettle

I am having a `XML` in the below mentioned format. I am using Get XML in pentaho to parse this. But I am not able get correct path to get all the values.
I want all the values of '**custom-attributes**'.

It is only giving me the value of only first attribute .i.e for 'sex' only.
Could anyone please help me how to get the values of other **custom-attributes**.

I have given the '**LoopXpath**' setting as :- `/names/name`

After pressing '**Get fields**' in fields tab as. I am automatically getting the custom-attribute xpath in Fields tab as mentioned below:-
 And it is giving the value of 'sex' only.

```
Name             |Xpath                                |Element     |  ResultType   |Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
custom-attributes |custom-attributes/custom-attribute  |Node         |Value of      |String



<names>
    <name>
      <firstname>ABCDEH</firstname>
      <lastname>JKLAM</lastname>
      <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="sex">male</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="height">169</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="weight">78</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="dateofbirth">09/09/1990</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="occupation">engineer</custom-attribute>
      </custom-attributes>
    </name>
  </names>
```

At last I want a single row like mentioned below:-

```
firstname lastname   sex    height    weight   dateofbirth   occupation

ABCDEH    JKLAM      male    160        78      09/09/1990    engineer
```

Could anyone please help me in that

Comment: The XPath itself is correct. Show how you are using it.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure what you have done in your code. Firstly in the "**Loop XPATH**" settings section of the step, define the parent node path instead of the '**custom-attribute**' path *(like you have mentioned above)* as below:

```
/names/name/custom-attributes//*
```

Secondly when you get fields attribute i.e the "**custom-attribute**", you will need to specify the `XPATH` as '**.**' (dot). This will do the recursion of the attribute values. Check the image below:

[image]

Finally you will get the recursive data as :

[image]

I have placed a sample code in [here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/b986d3b800991e7ce923). Please check it out for ref.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nice answer. I was trying to solve this issue But had no luck. I finally tried to use this step "XML Input Stream (StAX)"

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Thanks ;) ... Yes "XML Input Stream(StAX)" is also a good option. But the choice depends on the data volume. StAX will scale up in case of huge volume of data compared to my above answer. I assume all you need to do is to filter out the required attributes after the StAX input step.

Comment: @ Rhishu Yes true, I read about it. I have asked two questions on Pentaho but seems like Pentaho community is very low here in stackoverflow. Please look into them if you have time :)

Comment: @Rishu  thanks for the method.. I have asked another could you please look into that

Comment: @lovneeshjain this seems to be a different question than the one asked above!! Could you please edit your question. Both the questions doesnt seem to match !!!

Comment: @Rishu I have changed the question.Please have a look